Flask navbar link to autogenerated Swagger docs
Using flask_smorest to build APIs and auto-generate associated Swagger docs.
Also using flask_nav to create a navbar for all pages on site.
The Swagger docs url is localhost:5000/openapi/swagger-ui
Navbar currently looks like this:
    nav = Nav(app)
    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
    topbar = Navbar(
        View('Home', 'main.index'),
        View('Nodes', 'nodes.index'),
        Link('GitHub', 'https://github.com/somepage'),
        View('Swagger Docs', '???') ## What do I put here?
    )

How can I reference the Swagger docs link in my navbar code so it works when deployed?

After trying something and failing, Flask traceback actually told me the right answer:
View('API Docs', 'api-docs.openapi_swagger_ui')
